# Excel Min function not working

Tags: excel, excel-formula, min

I have an array that I am trying to return the maximum and minimum times corresponding to a reference number entered into O12.

i want it so that when i enter 10 into O12 my max function gives me 3:00 and my min gives me 1:00

```
A-----B-----C

10----------1:00

10----------3:00
```

```
{=MAX(INDEX((A6:A200=O12)*(C6:C200),0))}
{=MIN(INDEX((A6:A200=O12)*(C6:C200),0))}
```

My max function works perfectly and returns the highest number, but my min function always displays zero.

Answer (score 1):

When you use this "product" version, as opposed to an IF statement, any rows for which either of your two tests return a FALSE will generate a result of zero. This is since, when taking products of Booleans, TRUExFALSE=0 and FALSExTRUE=0. Hence your array passed to MIN will contain potentially many zeroes, causing undesirable results.

Using an IF statement, necessarily within an array formula, these same rows are assigned a Boolean FALSE, rather than zero. And, since MIN ignores Boolean values, this set-up guarantees correct results.

As an illustration, and just considering a range of A6:C10, let's assume that we have the following values:

O12: **"X"**

A6: **(blank)**
A7: **(blank)**
A8: **"X"**
A9: **(blank)**
A10: **"X"**

C6: **74**
C7: **64**
C8: **99**
C9: **58**
C10: **65**

The non-array formula:

```
=MIN(INDEX((A6:A10=O12)*(C6:C10),0))
```

will resolve as:

```
=MIN(INDEX(({"";"";"X";"";"X"}=O12)*(C6:C10),0))
```

which is:

```
=MIN(INDEX(({FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE})*(C6:C10),0))
```

i.e.:

```
=MIN(INDEX({0;0;99;0;65},0))
```

(Since the values in C6, C7 and C9 are being multiplied by FALSE their resulting product is 0.)

i.e.:

```
=MIN({0;0;99;0;65})
```

which is evidently 0.

However, the equivalent array formula:

```
=MIN(IF(A6:A10=O12,C6:C10))
```

resolves as:

```
=MIN(IF({"";"";"X";"";"X"}=O12,C6:C10))
```

which is:

```
=MIN(IF({FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE},C6:C10))
```

i.e.:

```
=MIN(IF({FALSE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE},{74;64;99;58;65}))
```

i.e.:

```
=MIN({FALSE;FALSE;99;FALSE;65})
```

which this time is 65, as desired.

If you really don't want to use an array formula (though I can't see why that would be the case - required keystroke combination aside, many people don't seem to realise that this workaround which employs the insertion of an (additional) INDEX function is no more efficient than the array set-up) then, if you have Excel 2010 or later, you can use AGGREGATE, i.e.:

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,C6:C10/(A6:A10=O12),1)
```

Regards

Comment: Great answer! It works fine as an array formula just as you say, but I don't understand why I can't use the same workaround as JNevill with the index function =MIN(INDEX(IF(A6:A10=O12,C6:C10),0))

Comment: It's just the way it is. Used in this way, and without array-entry, INDEX alone is unable to coerce the IF statement to operate over all elements within the array passed to it. May I ask why are you so insistent on avoiding CSE?

Comment: Personally I'm fine with them. You could argue if using index gave a consistent way to get the effect of an array formula some people might prefer to use it - but clearly it doesn't.

Comment: True, and some people attempt just that, and in all but a few cases (such as with an IF statement as here) it is a perfectly acceptable technique. I would add the caveat that, although circumventing the need to use CSE, it does have the drawback that it renders the formula a touch less reader-friendly. More importantly, whilst the insertion of a single INDEX formula for this purpose is perfectly fine, using up to two or three in a single formula to force array coercion is not to be recommended, in my opinion. Performance is noticeably worse in those cases than the equivalent array set-up.

Answer (score -1):

you're checking the minimum of something or 0. Since the something you're looking for is positive, 0 wins each time. Try using a large number to compare, e.g.

```
{=MIN(INDEX((A6:A200=O12)*(C6:C200),2E99))}
```

Comment: I see what you're saying. Tried that, just gave me a REF! though.

Comment: Also, I may be mistaken but I think that 0 is part of the index function as a row #